# Changing IMEI and Phone Model using Xamarin.Android 2019

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, imei

I'm using Xamarin in VS2019 and managed to read DeviceId/IMEI but what I want now is to be able to 
 change phone model and IMEI using Xamarin in VS2019 ?

Comment: why would you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  An application (at least, one without root privileges) does not have access to change this information.

Imagine the havoc an application could wreak if it could change that information.

Changing the IMEI could mess up the device's ability to associate with a cell network, breaking basic device functionality.

As for changing the phone model...there's no API for this because 1) it's a read-only system property and 2) the model of a phone is a physical property of the device, so there'd be no logical reason for an app to be able to change it.